# Problem in emp test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

**Class:**

```
global with sharing class emprolExtensionNew
{


    public Contact[] Availablerols {get;set;}
    public rol__c[] shoppingCart{get; set;}
    public emp__c theemp {get; set;} 
    public Contact[] ConRef{get;set;}
    public AccountTeamMember[] AtmRef {get;set;}
    public String tonSelect{get; set;}
    public String tocSelect{get; set;}
    public String toatmSelect{get; set;}
    public String toUnselect{get; set;}
    public String searchString{get; set;}
    public Boolean AccountRT{get; set;}
    public Boolean ContactRT{get; set;}
    public Boolean LeadRT{get; set;}
    public Boolean OpportunityRT{get; set;}
    public String UserID {get; set;}
    public Id recordtypeId {get;set;}
    public emp__c emps{get;set;}

    Map<Id,user> usermap =new Map<Id,user>([Select Id,Name from user]);
    Set<String> userNames = new Set<String>();
    private rol__c[] forDeletion = new rol__c[]{};
    private ApexPages.StandardController controller;

    //Constructor

    global emprolExtensionNew (ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
        this.controller= controller;
        if(controller.getrecord() == null)
        system.debug(controller.getrecord());


        //UserID = UserInfo.getname(); 

        //emping Custom Setting object for Recordtypes in emp object

        Record_Type_Name__c Accrt = Record_Type_Name__c.getValues('AccRecordTypeID');
        Record_Type_Name__c Conrt = Record_Type_Name__c.getValues('ConRecordTypeID');
        Record_Type_Name__c Leart = Record_Type_Name__c.getValues('LeaRecordTypeID');
        Record_Type_Name__c Opprt = Record_Type_Name__c.getValues('OppRecordTypeID');

        //Condition to check the record type for emp object 
        //system.debug(controller.RecordTypeId);
         if(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('RecordType') == Accrt.Record_Type__c){
            AccountRT = TRUE;
        }
        if(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('RecordType') == Conrt.Record_Type__c){
            ContactRT = TRUE;
        }
        if(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('RecordType') == Leart.Record_Type__c){
            LeadRT = TRUE;
        }
        if(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('RecordType') == Opprt.Record_Type__c){
            OpportunityRT = TRUE;
        }

        this.emps = (emp__c ) controller.getRecord(); 
        AtmRef = [select id, UserId, AccountId from AccountTeamMember where AccountId =: emps.AccountId__c ]; 
        ConRef = [select Id,Name, AccountId from contact where AccountId =:emps.AccountId__c ] ;

       { 

           shoppingCart = [Select id,name,empId__c,Contact_Id__c,emp_Date__c,rol__c.Contact_Id__r.Name from rol__c where id =: tonSelect ]; 

       }
       updateAvailableList();
     }


    public void updateAvailableList() 
    {

        UserID = UserInfo.getUserId(); 
        String qString =  'select id, Name, Title, Contact.MailingCity,Contact.MailingState,Contact.Account.Name from Contact where User_Id__c not in (select ID from User where id =: UserID )' ;
        system.debug(qString);

        if(searchString!=null)

        {          
            qString+= ' and ( Contact.Name like \'%' + searchString + '%\' or Contact.RACFID__c like \'%' + searchString + '%\' or Contact.Officer_Code__c like \'%' + searchString + '%\') ';                       
        }

       Set<Id> selectedEntries = new Set<Id>();
       if(tonSelect!=null)
        for(rol__c d : shoppingCart){
            selectedEntries.add(d.Contact_Id__c);
        }

        if(selectedEntries.size()>0){
            String tempFilter = ' and id not in (';
            for(id i : selectedEntries){
                tempFilter+= '\'' + (String)i + '\',';
            }
            String extraFilter = tempFilter.substring(0,tempFilter.length()-1);
            extraFilter+= ')';

            qString+= extraFilter;
        } 

        qString+= ' order by Name';
        qString+= ' limit 12';
        system.debug('qString:' +qString );               
        Availablerols = database.query(qString);
        system.debug(Availablerols);

    } 

    public void addToShoppingCart()

    // This function runs when a user hits "select" button next to a rol

    { 
      for(Contact part : Availablerols)
       {
        if((String)part.id==tonSelect)
            {

                shoppingCart.add(new rol__c (Contact_Id__c =part.id));
                system.debug(shoppingCart);
                system.debug('rol select size' + shoppingCart.size());

                break;
            }          

        }    
        updateAvailableList();  
    } 

 public void AccountTeamMemberList()

     // This function runs when a user hits "select" button next to a Account Contact

    {


        //emp__c emps = (emp__c ) controller.getRecord(); 
        //AtmRef = [select id, UserId, AccountId from AccountTeamMember where AccountId =: emps.AccountId__c ]; 


    for(AccountTeamMember partsatm : AtmRef )
         {
            system.debug(partsatm.UserId);
            if(partsatm.UserId != null)
            {
                User us = usermap.get(partsatm.UserId);
                userNames.add(us.Name);

                system.debug(us.Name);
            }
         }

          if(userNames.size() > 0)
        {
            List<Contact> userNameContacts = [Select Id, Name from Contact where Name IN : userNames and Contact_Type__c='Key Employee' and Salesforce_User__c=true];
            {
                for(AccountTeamMember partsatm : AtmRef )

          {

             User us = usermap.get(partsatm.UserId);
             system.debug(partsatm.UserId);
              Contact foundContact;
                 for(Contact contact : userNameContacts)
                 {
                      system.debug(contact.Name);
                      system.debug(us.Name);                      
                      if(contact.Name == us.Name)
                      {
                            foundContact = contact;
                            break;
                      }
                 }
                 if(foundContact != null && partsatm.id==toatmSelect)
                 {
                      rol__c  partatm = new rol__c();
                      partatm.Contact_Id__c = foundContact.Id;
                      //addrol.add(partatm);
                      //system.debug(addrol);
                      system.debug(partatm);
                      shoppingCart.add(partatm);
                 }

        }

      updateAvailableList();  

    }

   }
 }


 public void ContactList()
    {
        //emp__c emps = (emp__c ) controller.getRecord();
        //ConRef = [select Id,Name, AccountId from contact where AccountId =:emps.AccountId__c and id =: tocSelect] ;
        //system.debug(ConRef);

        for(Contact parts : ConRef )
        {
        if((String)parts.id==tocSelect)
            {
                shoppingCart.add(new rol__c(Contact_Id__c=parts.id));
                system.debug(shoppingCart.size());
                break;
            }          
        }

       updateAvailableList();  

    } 

 public void InVFPage()

     // This function runs when a user selects Account lookup field

    {
        this.emps = (emp__c ) controller.getRecord(); 
        AtmRef = [select id, UserId, AccountId from AccountTeamMember where AccountId =: emps.AccountId__c ]; 
        ConRef = [select Id,Name, AccountId from contact where AccountId =:emps.AccountId__c ] ;
    }   


 public PageReference removeFromShoppingCart(){

        // This function runs when a user hits "remove" on "Selected rol" section

        Integer count = 0;

        for(rol__c del : shoppingCart){
            if((String)del.Contact_Id__c==toUnselect){

                if(del.Id!=null)
                    forDeletion.add(del);

                shoppingCart.remove(count);
                break;
            }
            count++;
        }

        updateAvailableList();

        return null;
    }



     // This function runs when user hits save button

     public PageReference onSave(){

        try{

            PageReference pageRef = controller.save();
            system.debug(controller.getrecord().id);

                if(shoppingCart.size()>0) 

                  for (rol__c partmember : shoppingCart ){
                     partmember.empId__c=controller.getrecord().id;
                     System.debug(partmember.empId__c);
                  }

                  System.debug('size' +shoppingCart.size());
                  insert(shoppingCart);
                }


            catch(Exception e){
            ApexPages.addMessages(e);
            return null;
        }  
           System.debug('completed');

        // After save return the user to the emp
       return new PageReference('/' + controller.getrecord().id);  
    }     
}
```

**test class:**

```
@istest(seealldata=true)
Public class Test_emprolExtensionNew1
{
     public static testMethod void theTests()
    {
        Profile p = [select id from profile where name='Bank Admin'];
        User testUser = new User(alias = 'u1', email='vidhyasagaran_muralidharan@keybank.com',
           emailencodingkey='UTF-8', lastname='Testing', languagelocalekey='en_US',
           localesidkey='en_US', profileid = p.Id, country='United States',
           timezonesidkey='America/Los_Angeles', username='vidhyasagaran_muralidharan@keybank.com',PLOB__c='support',PLOB_Alias__c='support');             
        insert testUser;
        RecordType opprt =[select id,name from recordtype where name ='Account emp'];

        Account acc = new Account(name ='Acc Test');
        insert acc;

        contact con = new contact(LastName='Mr. Dhanesh Subramanian',RACFID__c='HINDF', Officer_Code__c='HINDF',Contact_Type__c='Key Employee',AccountId=acc.id,Salesforce_User__c=true,User_Id__c=testUser.Id );
        insert con;    
        PageReference pageRef = Page.empCustomNew;
        pageRef.getParameters().put('id',opprt.Id);
        Test.setCurrentPageReference(pageRef);

        ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(opprt);
        emprolExtensionNew e = new  emprolExtensionNew(sc);

        Integer startCount = e.ShoppingCart.size();


        e.searchString = con.name;
        e.updateAvailableList();

        e.tonSelect= e.Availablerols[0].Id;
        e.addToShoppingCart();        

        e.toUnselect = e.ShoppingCart[0].id;
        e.removeFromShoppingCart();
        e.ContactList();
        e.AccountTeamMemberList();
        e.onSave();

    }
}
```

**Error:**

> Class.emprolExtensionNew.: line 68, column 1
>   Class.Test_emprolExtensionNew1.theTests: line 24, column 1
>   System.TypeException: Invalid conversion from runtime type RecordType
>   to emp__c.

kinldy help to resolve the issue in the test class.

Answer (score 2):

The `StandardController` you are creating in your test is for `RecordType`:

```
  RecordType opprt =[select id,name from recordtype where name ='Account emp'];
  ...
  ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(opprt);
  emprolExtensionNew e = new  emprolExtensionNew(sc);
```

But when your controller code gets the record back it is casting it to a `emp__c`

```
this.emps = (emp__c ) controller.getRecord();
```

The error is saying that you can not cast `RecordType` to `emp__c`. You should be creating the `StandardController` with an `emp__c`.

Comment: @Barcotter-yes i got your point the problem here is i am redirecting to new visualforce page based on record type.In the code i have used this because based on account lookup field i should get my related contact and account team member so i used this line-this.emps = (emp__c ) controller.getRecord();.Since it is new record creation visualforce page. i have used this logic for the test class.